# HAProxy should not forward an incoming request to down instance

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, cluster, nginx

In my scenario, I have 2 servers, both are communicating with HAProxy. When a request comes in, HAProxy splits the request and sends it to both servers, following a round robin method. If in any case my first instance goes down, at that time HAProxy should come to know that one of the servers are down and it should not forward any requests to that server. It should only communicate with the other server for every request.

Can anybody tell me how I can configure my HAProxy for above scenario, please?

Comment: Do you have an `/etc/haproxy.cfg` that you've started with?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this tutorial is exactly what you're looking for. The tutorial is titled: [Setting Up A High-Availability Load Balancer (With Failover and Session Support) With HAProxy/Heartbeat On Debian Lenny](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-high-availability-load-balancer-with-haproxy-heartbeat-on-debian-lenny).

In general you're /etc/haproxy.cfg file will look similar to this:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        user haproxy
        group haproxy

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        redispatch
        maxconn         2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

listen webfarm 192.168.0.99:80
       mode http
       stats enable
       stats auth someuser:somepassword
       balance roundrobin
       cookie JSESSIONID prefix
       option httpclose
       option forwardfor
       option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
       server webA 192.168.0.102:80 cookie A check
       server webB 192.168.0.103:80 cookie B check
```

You'll need to reconfigure this file and change the frontend webfarm IP address to whatever is yours. Also you'll need to repoint the server lines to your internal backend servers' IP addresses.